# .htaccess second RewriteRule note working

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a PHP page like `example.com/new/info.php?title=example`. The `.htaccess` is in folder `/new/`. I tried it in the main directory also. My `.htaccess` looks like this:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ page.php?title=$1 [QSA,L,NC]

RewriteRule ^info/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ info.php?title=$1 [QSA,L,NC]
```

The first Rule is working, but the second sends no `GET['title']` to the server. The site `info.php` loads but without the variable. I have tested it on my localhost and it's working. I load it on my webspace and the second rule is not working.

I tried it also without new directory `example.com/info.php?title=example` and same not work.

What is my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have `MultiViews` enabled (possibly in the server config). You need to disable `MultiViews` for this to work. Add the following at the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

With MultiViews enabled, mod_negotiation will issue an internal subrequest for `info.php` when making a request for `/info/example/` - before your mod_rewrite rule is processed, so no parameters are passed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have solved the problem. I have create a empty folder with Name „info“ and now it works. I dont know. But i test it with your solution. Thanks!

Comment: Disabling MutliViews, as stated in my answer should have also resolved this, and would be the prefered way to solve this. Creating an empty directory would have prevented mod_negotiation from rewriting the request.

Comment: If this answered your question then please mark it as accepted (checkmark below the voting arrows on the left) to remove it from the unanswered question queue. Once you have 15+ rep then you can also upvote answers you find useful. Thanks, much appreciated. :)